# What is wrong with this Ruby case control code?

Tags: ruby, switch-statement

def identify_class(obj)

```
result = case obj
when obj.kind_of? Hacker  then "It's a Hacker!"
when obj.kind_of? Submission then "It's a Submission!"
when obj.kind_of? TestCase then "It's a TestCase!"
when obj.kind_of? Contest then "It's a Contest!"
    end

puts result   

end
```

> syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_then or ',' or';' or 
>   '\n'

after the result = case obj statement and a bunch of

> syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting keyword_end

after every when statement with this final excepting end of input error at the end.

Wont even work if I delete every when statement except for one, although the second error is gone.

I tried using the if else ladder but that won't also work

Does work with one single if obj.kind_of? Hacker puts "It's a ...."

Comment: Why you use **then** in ruby

Comment: I've edited your question to remove the Rails tag, since this is a general Ruby question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby there are two types of case expression, and you seem to be confusing them. The first is basically the same as an `if...elsif...end` expression, and looks like this:

```
case
when boolean_expression
  # code executed if boolean_expression is truthy
when other_expression
  # code executed if other_expression is truthy
# other whens ...
end
```

Note how there isn’t anything after `case` before the first `when`. In this type of `case` statement the code associated with the first expression that evaluates to true will be executed, non of the rest will.

The other kind of `case` statement takes an argument and compares that argument with each of the `when` clauses:

```
case obj
when type1
  # some code if type1 === obj
when other_type
  # some code if other_type === obj
# other whens ...
end
```

Here there is an argument to `case` (`obj` in this example). This is compared to the argument to each `when` clause in turn using [`===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D), and the associated code is run for the first one where that comparison is true.

Note that this type of `case` can be written like the first type:

```
case
when type1 === obj
# etc...
```

In your case you start with `case obj`, which indicates the second type. You then use `obj` in each `when` clause like you would in the first kind.

(The actual error you are getting is actually just a syntax error caused by a bit of an ambiguity in the Ruby syntax, but even if you fixed that your code wouldn’t work as you’d expect.)

Module [overrides `===` to check if the arg is an instance](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D), so for your use you can just do this:

```
result = case obj
when Hacker  then "It's a Hacker!"
when Submission then "It's a Submission!"
when TestCase then "It's a TestCase!"
when Contest then "It's a Contest!"
end
```

Comment: Thank you, works fine now. I also tried something else `r = case when obj.kind_of?(Hacker) then "It's a Hacker" puts r` removing the case obj works that way too.